# How to get intellisense for Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 10 for OS X Yosemite and trying to get intellisense for bootstrap. I used this link but so far it has not worked out:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have bootstrap.js in your project files or set up as External library (in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries - Add..).